# Exactly how does kickstart encrypt a partition?

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, encryption, luks

Let's say for example I have this line in the pre section of my kickstart file:

```
part / --asprimary --fstype="ext4" --size=10000 --encrypted --passphrase=pass1
```

Great, but, how does that work? Exactly how does "--encrypted" encrypt the partition? Does it use: `cryptsetup luksFormat ...`?

A quick google search can tell me how to use cryptsetup, but a quick google search does not tell me exactly what the "--encryption" flag does. I need to reproduce what it does on a non-encrypted partition in the same exact fashion.

Comment: Yes, it's LUKS, same as you would have done manually.

Comment: ...... so I can assume that all the options for `cryptsetup luksFormat` are whatever I want them to be.......

Comment: Hmm. The [installer source code](https://github.com/rhinstaller/anaconda) is available. It may make interesting reading.

Comment: OOOOOooo that is the start of what I was looking for. Now time to digest.

Answer (score 1):

It uses LUKS, the options you can supply are [documented, EL6 and 7 are the same](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-options.html)

- --cipher=
- --passphrase=
- --escrowcert=URL_of_X.509_certificate
- --escrowcert=URL_of_X.509_certificate

It doesn't appear that you can supply arbitrary `cryptsetup luksFormat ...` options.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. The documentation says that the cipher is defaulted to, `aes-xts-plain64`, which is great, but what other options do I need to provide to the `cryptsetup luksFormat` command to get the same encryption? So, `cryptsetup --cipher aes-xts-plain64 luksFormat /dev/sda5` will set the right cipher, but what about all the other <options> available for luksFormat shown in the man page of cryptsetup? Does anaconda utilize those? Basically, how do I recreate the same encryption that "--encrypted" provides?